Ubuntu 24.04 video playback on VirtualBox Choppy
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on VirtualBox fully up to date, and my Host OS (Windows 11) is fully up to date as well. VLC won't play any mp4 or other files, and the built-in player has choppy video play and audio here and there as well. Looking for suggestions as to what I can do to improve? I have tried a few command line tricks and have not gotten results. I have noticed audio is choppy as well. Thank You!

Enable hardware graphics acceleration. Assign at least 128MB of VRAM in Virtualbox settings. Then, install the latest VirtualBox guest additions.
